# how to implement elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

can kibana's console (in Dev Tools) be used for writing and implementing elasticsearch ? I am new to elasticsearch and very confused when it comes to doing hands-on it. thank you in advance.

Comment: That depends what you mean by "implementing", but you can send commands to elasticsearch's REST api from it. You can also use any tool like Postman to create HTTP requests, but Kibana can make it somewhat more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

kibana Dev tools makes calling elastic search API's easier so you can develop what ever you want in kibana Dev tools to make aggregation call or make query string to call the API's.
on the other hand you should use it with an SDK in your application like Elasticsearch JS for javascript so you can use the developed queries and aggregations in kibana to be used in your application and more you can monitor your shards health or put mapping for your indexes and more of functionality which can be found in [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html), Although, you can find JS API's Documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kibana Dev Tools to invoke REST API commands to perform cluster level actions such as taking snapshots, restore etc and also index simple documents. But, if you are looking to writing data to Elastic on a regular basis like ingesting server/ app logs or server metrics (CPU, memory, Disk usage etc) you should look at installing filebeats or metricbeats.